# how to loading images using Asynchronous GCD For UITableviewcell/

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm loading images for my uitableview asynchronously using GCD, but there is a problem - when scrolling down UITableview the images are dissappeared on top.And sometimes the images are not displayed in UITableviewcell. This is my code.please give me any idea.Is there any error in my code.Please help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";   
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
 if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];  
 }
image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)];

[cell.contentView addSubview:image];

 str=att.classimage;

url=@"My URL";

if(str!=nil){

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSString *imageStr=[url stringByAppendingString:str];
           image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageStr];               
         });      
    });
    image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-logo.png"];   
}
return cell;        
}
```

Comment: The cell Identifier you are using to dequeue is @"cell" and identifier while alloc/initing cell is @"identifier".

Comment: And fixed how you add the imageView. currently it is always adding while the cellForRow is being called

Comment: I would like to suggest you to cache images if images are coming from server.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting Image check if that cell is still in memory.

```
UITableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (updateCell)
{
    yourImageView.image = [imagePost fixOrientation];
}
```

I am doing similar thing, but Using NSURLConnection.

```
NSURL *postImage  =   [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];

NSMutableURLRequest *imageRequest    =   [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:postImage cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
[imageRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:imageRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     imagePost = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; // UIImage Object

     UITableViewCell *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     if (updateCell)
     {
         postImageView.image = [imagePost fixOrientation];// setting my ImageView
     }
 }];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

    static NSString *identifier=@"cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];  
       UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)];
       imageView.tag = 100;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];    
    }

   str=att.classimage;
   url=@"My URL";
   UIImageView *cellImageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
   cellImageView.image = nil;
   if(str!=nil) {
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
   dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
      NSString *imageStr = [url stringByAppendingString:str];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]]];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{            
        cellImageView.image = image;               
      });      
    });
   }
   return cell;        
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But i got error in cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSUrl urlWithString:imageStr]]; . in this line i got error like "No known class method for selector urlWithString.". Please help me friend

Comment: thanks brother.images will be displayed brother.but getting another problem.if i scroll the UITableview from top to bottom.And again i scroll bottom to top the images are automatically changed.previously displayed images are not displayed.new images will be displayed

Comment: Updated code, you have to cache the images with some Mapping so that everytime same images are not loaded from net. As @PKS method in his answer better to use AFNetworking. It handles the caching for you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AFNetworknig` for showing images from remote URL.

[get AFNetworking from here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

just

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
    [imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeHolderImage"]];
```